# webform_multifile required doesn't work

Tags: 7, webforms

I added the webform_multifile to my webform and I configured it as a required field.

But even if I do not download files, the form validates correctly.

And if I download image, I can't find it in my sites/default/files/webform neither in my data base..

Any idea please? Thank you!

Comment: By “download” do you mean “upload”?

Comment: Yes. Finally I replaced the webform_multifile module by the webform_multiple_file module and it's ok. Thanks Sir